# Where to download Hive 0.12 source?

Tags: hive

I have raised a beeline bug and would like to test the patch, so I'm trying to recompile Hive 0.12 with the patch, but the problem that it seems Apache only host versions 0.13.1+:
http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hive/

Anybody knows a place to find older versions (0.12)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can find the source code you're looking for here [Apache Hive releases page](https://github.com/apache/hive/releases)

Now it seems to be hosted on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Strange, it would have been nice to see message about older versions of Apache's page.